How does Diagonalizing Mass Terms Affect the Lagrangian?
One thing I don't get about mass diagonalization, is doesn't this also change the kinetic terms of your theory? You would get some off-diagonal kinetic terms. How do we deal with this?
What also bothers me is, in the context of neutrinos, we can introduce a sterile right handed neutrino and then diagonalize the mass terms, giving physical fields v' and N:
$$\nu_L = \cos\theta v'_L + \sin\theta N_L,  
\nu_R = -\sin\theta v'R + \cos\theta N_R.$$
You can just re-write your Langrangian in terms of these new fields v' and N. These new fields, in the simplest model, can be taken to be Majorana, which makes some sense looking at their mass terms.
$$ \nu_R = \nu_L^c , N_R = N_L^c$$
But what doesn't make sense is that since they are related to the LH neutrino by some mixing angle, I would guess that they would carry some sort of quantum numbers? Otherwise, where did the quantum numbers go?
I would assume that they didn't just go to one field, because then this would imply that the RH neutrino (written in terms of both $v'$ and $N$ as well) would necessarily carry some quantum number, contrary to its definition

This is a response to the first part of your question, not related to the neutrino physics specifically.
Suppose we start with a generic Lagrangian with $N$ scalar fields where both the kinetic and mass terms are undiagonalized
$$
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2} Z_{ab} \partial_\mu \phi^a \partial^\mu \phi^b - \frac{1}{2} M_{ab} \phi^a \phi^b
$$
Then we do a unitary transformation $\phi^a \rightarrow \bar{\phi}^a = U^{ab} \phi^b$ (with $U^\dagger = U^{-1}$) to diagonalize the kinetic term
$$
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2} Z_a \delta_{ab} \partial_\mu \bar{\phi}^a \partial^\mu \bar{\phi}^b - \frac{1}{2} \bar{M}_{ab} \bar{\phi}^a \bar{\phi}^b
$$
where $\bar{M} = U^\dagger M U$.
I'm abusing Einstein notation by writing $Z_a \delta_{ab}$, but hopefully you get the idea that this is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $Z_a$. Also, to avoid notational clutter, I'm not intro
Now here is the key idea. We can do a non-unitary transformation of the fields by rescaling, to absorb the eigenvalues $Z_a$. We perform the transformation $\bar{\phi}^a \rightarrow \psi^a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{Z}^a} \bar{\phi}^a$. Then the Lagrangian becomes
$$
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \psi^a \partial^\mu \psi^a - \frac{1}{2} m_{ab} \psi^a \psi^b
$$
where $m_{ab} = \bar{M}_{ab} / Z_a$.
Now the last step is that we do a unitary transformation $\psi^a \rightarrow V^{ab} \bar{\psi}^b$ with $V^\dagger = V^{-1}$ to diagonalize the mass term. At this point, the the kinetic "matrix" is just proportional to the identity matrix, so it is unaffected by this transformation. Therefore we have
$$
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \bar{\psi}^a \partial^\mu \bar{\psi}^a - \frac{1}{2} m_a^2 \delta_{ab} \partial_\mu \bar{\psi}^a  \partial^\mu \bar{\psi}^b
$$
In other words, this sequence of transformations has let us diagonalize both the kinetic and mass terms. The key step was performing a non-unitary rescaling of the fields so that the kinetic matrix was proportional to the identity matrix. Having a standard coefficient of all of the kinetic terms for all of the fields, with no mixing in the kinetic term, is sometimes called "canonical normalization."

Ah of course, I need to use the unitarity condition and the fact that the transformation commutes with the derivative. This makes kinetic terms easy to handle. In the context of neutrino physics though there seems to be a subtlety. It seems like these arguments only work if all of the kinetic terms are the same. But if we're working with neutrinos the LH kinetic term differs from the RH kinetic term. How do we resolve this? My guess is to write out the expanded form of the covariant derivative and treat gauge interactions separately.

@SamuelFGC I'm not an expert on neutrino physics, but can't you rescale the right handed and left handed neutrinos separately to canonically normalize both sets of kinetic terms?
